# Adding Header to Request in android webiew

Tags: android, webview, http-headers

I have an url which has to be loaded in web view, but I need to pass an header to the request.

I tried using setting headers to web view, using HashMap but it didn't worked.

I found the solutions such as web view intercepting client but did not get a proper example of how to load the url.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve it.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. If you can provide more information, I think you will get a better solution for this.

Comment: See, I have a url which has to be loaded in webview but I need to pass authorization header to that url while loading.

Comment: You just pass the extra header in loadUrl method as the third parameter,you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: No, the extra header thing is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> extraHeaders)
```

For adding headers to resources loading requests, make custom WebViewClient and override:

```
API 24+:
WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
or
WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate WebResourceResponse part?